# I can't get blog posts into 'featured areas' on homepage

Tags: plugins

Forgive the newbie question but i'm starting up a new blog using wordpress and, having installed a template and begun the very initial steps of setting it up, i've got an issue with not being able to configure the 'featured areas' on the homepage to be able to pull in the blog posts.

The URL is http://theformula1blog.com/

Have played around and tried to configure this way but not been able to get it to work. Ideally i'd have the most three recent posts in the featured areas and then potentially a couple more below them.

Any tip would be appreciated as i get to grips with configuring WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note you are using the **Minamaze** theme, correct? The problem here is the featured area, is exactly that, an area to manually enter featured content. You cannot automatically add posts to these areas.

To configure them, you need to go into the admin, choose appearance, then customize.

In here, choose Theme Options, then Homepage (Featured) and this will open the section to edit the content of the three areas.

Answer (score 1):

Usually setting a post as sticky post sets it to the featured area. From wp-admin editor, set a post as sticky post (option is hidden below `Publish -> Visibility: Public`).

Same way set multiple posts as sticky post and they should appear as featured posts for your theme.

Comment: @ExecuKev This may work or may not depending on your active theme. Some themes use sticky posts as featured posts, others may have theme options under `Appearance` menu where you can set featured posts manually. If this doesn't work then check what option your active theme is providing for featured posts.